# Arcpy Update Cursor-Overwrite values in field based on CSV

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-2.7

I have a CSV file called `Modifications`. The header has two entries, `Rental Object` and `Rental Object Name`. The `Rental Object` is a string that has matching values in a FGDB feature class where the column is called `Property_Ref`. This attribute table also contains a field called `Descriptio`. I need to update this `Descriptio` with the values from `Rental Object Name` in the CSV. The `Rental Object` in the CSV and the `Property_Ref` match. I'm not sure how to complete this. Below is as far as I've progressed.

```
# Update Records to be Archived:
import csv, arcpy
fc = "U:/Data/Lease_Plans.gdb/LeasePlans_SAP_NOs_Descs"
Modifications= "U:/Data/Rental_Object_Modifications.csv"

#Read the CSV File
with open(Modifications, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mydict = dict((rows[0],rows[1]) for rows in reader)

fc_fields = ('Property_Ref','Descriptio')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fc_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #Not sure how to structure this.

del cursor
```

Comment: Is `Rental Object` value unique for all rows in the CSV file?

Comment: you can join a csv file with a table in arcmap. have you tried joining and then using the field calculator to populate the desired field?

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping to make this part of a much large automation project eventually so was trying to avoid a join.

Answer (score 3):

If the dictionary is built properly, and it looks like it is, you should be able to compare the 'Property_Ref' values to the dictionary keys ('Rental_Object') with a loop.  You should iterate over the FeatureClass rows and update the 'Descripto' field to the *value* of the key in **my_dict**.

Also, don't forget to make the fc_fields variable a list and not a tuple.

```
fc_fields = ['Property_Ref', 'Descriptio']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fc_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in my_dict:
            row[1] = my_dict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor
```

Comment: No need for `del cursor`, as garbage collection will delete it at the conclusion of the `with` block.

Comment: @nmpeterson  I keep getting a <da.SearchCursor object> present while running from IDLE.  Can you send info on this, please?

Comment: It's probably just a delay in the automatic garbage collection. I wouldn't be concerned about it. Whatever variables you initialize as part of a `with` are designed to be temporary, guaranteed to exist only over the life of the `with` block.